# Read a string line by line using c++

Tags: c++

I have a `std::string` with multiple lines and I need to read it line by line.
Please show me how to do it with a small example.

Ex: I have a string `string h;`

h will be:

```
Hello there.
How are you today?
I am fine, thank you.
```

I need to extract `Hello there.`, `How are you today?`, and `I am fine, thank you.` somehow.

Comment: when you say `multiple link` you actually mean it or you meant `lines`?

Comment: please see the last paragraph of the "How do I ask questions here?" section of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream f("line1\nline2\nline3");
    std::string line;    
    while (std::getline(f, line)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There are several ways to do that.

You can use `std::string::find` in a loop for `'\n'` characters and substr() between the positions.

You can use `std::istringstream` and `std::getline( istr, line )` (Probably the easiest)

You can use `boost::tokenize`

Answer (score 5):

this would help you : 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

Comment: "cplusplus.com" has lots of errors (though I can't see any obvious ones on that page), and using the global `std::getline` is better so that you can use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather not use streams:

```
int main() {
  string out = "line1\nline2\nline3";
  size_t start = 0;
  size_t end;
  while (1) {
    string this_line;
    if ((end = out.find("\n", start)) == string::npos) {
      if (!(this_line = out.substr(start)).empty()) {
        printf("%s\n", this_line.c_str());
      }

      break;
    }

    this_line = out.substr(start, end - start);
    printf("%s\n", this_line.c_str());
    start = end + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Streams are certainly easier, but sometimes you have a coding standard that disallows streams :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some standard implementation for a function which can return a particular line from a string. I came across this question and the accepted answer is very useful. I also have my own implementation which I would like to share:

```
// CODE: A
std::string getLine(const std::string& str, int line)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    if (line < 0)
        return std::string();

    while ((line-- > 0) and (pos < str.length()))
        pos = str.find("\n", pos) + 1;
    if (pos >= str.length())
        return std::string();
    size_t end = str.find("\n", pos);
    return str.substr(pos, (end == std::string::npos ? std::string::npos : (end - pos + 1)));
}
```

But I have replaced my own implementation with the one shown in the accepted answer as it uses standard function and would be less bug-prone..

```
// CODE: B
std::string getLine(const std::string& str, int lineNo)
{
    std::string line;
    std::istringstream stream(str);
    while (lineNo-- >= 0)
        std::getline(stream, line);
    return line;
}
```

There is behavioral difference between the two implementations. `CODE: B` removes the newline from each line it returns. `CODE: A` doesn't remove newline.

**My intention of posting my answer to this not-active question is to make others see possible implementations.**

**NOTE:**

I didn't want any kind of optimization and wanted to perform a task given to me in a Hackathon!