# another C++ equivalent for the followingtwo lines of code

Tags: c++

Sorry for such a vague title.
Basically, I am trying to hack a function to suit my needs. But lately I have been working a lot on python and my c++ is bit rusty.

So earlier my function took a

```
 int func(FILE *f)  
 { .....
   if (fgets(line, MM_MAX_LINE_LENGTH, f) == NULL) 
    return MM_PREMATURE_EOF;

if (sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s %s", banner, mtx, crd, data_type, 
    storage_scheme) != 5)
    return MM_PREMATURE_EOF;

 }
```

now instead of this I am directly inputing the string data

```
 int func(std::string *data)  
   { .....
   // how should I modify this if statment..I want to parse the same file
   // but instead it is in form of one giant string

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059049/read-an-string-line-by-line-using-c) is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same code, just convert the data in the `std::string` into a C string.

```
sscanf(data->c_str(), "%s %s %s %s %s", //...);
```

However, you should consider passing in a const reference, since you are probably not planning on modifying your input data:

```
int func(const std::string &data) {
    //...
    if (sscanf(data.c_str(), //...)) {
        //...
    }
}
```