# String arrays output

Tags: c++, arrays, string

How can I get the output of this program to work correctly? I'm not sure why the string array won't store my values and then output them at the end of my program. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int score[100], score1 = -1;
    string word[100];
    do
    {
        score1 = score1 + 1;
        cout << "Please enter a score (-1 to stop): ";
        cin >> score[score1];
    }
    while (score[score1] != -1);
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < score1; x++)
        {
            cout << "Enter a string: ";
            getline(cin,word[x]);
            cin.ignore();
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < score1; x++)
        {
            cout << score[x] << "::" << word[x] << endl; // need output to be 88:: hello there.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's not working? Give the error message, expected output, what your program actually does...

Comment: Please post some sample input and output values so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Theres no error message. The input for example would be 15, 16, 17... hello there!, how are you?, I am fine ... and output should be 15 :: hello there! .. etc

Comment: What I get is 15:: (blank) 16:: ello there! 17 :: ow are you?

Answer (score 1):

I've corrected your code. Try something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int score[100], score1 = -1;
    char word[100][100];
    do
    {
        score1++;
        cout << "Please enter a score (-1 to stop): ";
        cin >> score[score1];
    }
    while (score[score1] != -1);

    cin.ignore();

    for (int x = 0; x < score1; x++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a string: ";
        cin.getline(word[x], 100);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < score1; x++)
    {
        cout << score[x] << "::" << word[x] << endl; // need output to be 88:: hello there.
    }

}
```

OK what have I done? First of all I delete extra *{*. When I've seen your code for the first time I have no idea if there is do..while loop or while loop in do.while. Next I change string array to char array, just because I know how to read line to char array. When I need to read line to string I always use my own function, but if you really want to use string [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059112/1387612) is great example. Rest is quite obvious. *cin.ignore()* is required because new line character stays in buffer so we need to omit it.

**EDIT:**
I've just found better way to fix your code. Everything is OK but you need to move *cin.ignore()* and place it just after *while (score[score1] != -1);*. Because wright now you are ignoring first char of every line and you need only ignore new line after user type -1. [Fixed code.](http://ideone.com/E6JQx)

Comment: It would be good if you explained why this works but the OP's code doesn't.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n')` to ignore all pending input?

Comment: No, you just need to ignore one '\n' that is after user type -1. getline reads whole line with '\n' so there is no need to do it in loop

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop, you increment "score1" before the first value is assigned. That places your values in the score[] array starting at index 1. However, in the "for" loop below, you start your indexing at 0, meaning that your score/string associations will be off by one.

Comment: No, `score1` is initialised to `-1`, so the first index used is 0.

Comment: Argh, my bad, you're absolutely right. Some sample input and output would help, then.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
getline(cin,word[x]);
cin.ignore();
```

with

```
cin >> word[x];
```

and then try figuring out where you went wrong.

Comment: This solution works as long as I don't have any spaces. If I try to input hello, there! ill get enter string: enter string: